# Angular scope.$on('$destroy')

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive with a `link` function that, inside it, performs a `scope.$on('$destroy', cleanup)`.

I'd like to open the browser's JavaScript console and trigger the `$destroy` to make sure `cleanup` is getting called and executing correctly.

How can I do this?

Inside the `link` function, I've set `window.blahblah = scope;`, then tried `window.blahblah.trigger('$destroy')` in the JavaScript console, but not firing.

Eventually I'm going to have to write a test in the `.spec.js` file for this directive, so knowing how to do that, too, would be helpful.

Comment: Sounds like this would be something to handle in a unit or midway test; is that the situation you are describing? It sort of sounds like you're wanting to have it fire within the non-test code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can destroy it directly by calling `$scope.$destroy()`, so in your case the code would be

```
window.blahblah.$destroy();
```

or if you just want to test the listener without destroying for real you can call `$scope.$broadcast('$destroy')` instead.

```
window.blahblah.$broadcast('$destroy');
```